# Show that, for any matrix $A$, the solutions to $AX=0$ form a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that, for any matrix $A$, the solutions to $AX=0$ form a vector space.

I know the defn of vector spaces, and how to check it (closed under addition and multiplication). My attempt at this proof was to divide it up in two parts

a) assume A is invertible.

b) assume A is not invertible.

There probably is a smarter way to create a proof, and this would be a pretty standard quesiton.

Comment: You do not use the invertibility of $A$ anywhere. So it is not to be considered.

Comment: Assume nothing: prove directly closedeness of sum and scalar multiplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set all such vectors $X$ is closed under both operations as follows
$$A(\lambda X)=\lambda(AX)=0
\\A(X+Y)=AX+AY=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$, $y$ be solutions and let $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}$.

Now you see $\lambda\cdot x + y$ is a solution. (by application of $A$ and it's linearity)